# Vb.Net DGV custom column with custom cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

1. I want to build a custom column and cell for the DGV which holds various telephone numbers with their country codes, flags and formats.
2. I have tried: i managed to make it display what i wanted in the inherited  DataGridViewTextBoxCell Paint event. The problem is that it only displays the flags when the cell is painted, but what i want is to generate new properties for the cell which hold the country flag and the country code so i could later use them. What i don't know is what methods to override in column or cell to save that property when the data is loaded. I could save it on the Paint method, but then it will only save that property for the visible cells, so no...
3. What i have so far:

   Imports System.ComponentModel
   Imports System.IO
   Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
   Imports ExcelDataReader
   Public Class TelefonColumn
   Inherits DataGridViewColumn

   ```
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New TelefonCell())
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property CellTemplate As DataGridViewCell
        Get
            Return MyBase.CellTemplate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)

            If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not value.[GetType]().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(TelefonCell)) Then
                Throw New InvalidCastException("Nu e in formatul corect {TelefonColumn\CellTemplate}!")
            End If

            MyBase.CellTemplate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim c As TelefonColumn = CType(MyBase.Clone(), TelefonColumn)
        Return c
    End Function
   ```

   End Class

   Public Class TelefonCell
   Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

   ```
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim c As TelefonCell = CType(MyBase.Clone(), TelefonCell)
        Return c
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Paint(graphics As Graphics, clipBounds As Rectangle, cellBounds As Rectangle, rowIndex As Integer, cellState As DataGridViewElementStates, value As Object, formattedValue As Object, errorText As String, cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle, advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle, paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)

        Dim parent As TelefonColumn = CType(Me.OwningColumn, TelefonColumn)
        Dim fnt As Font = parent.InheritedStyle.Font
        Dim textColor As Color = parent.InheritedStyle.ForeColor

        Dim telValue As String = ""
        Dim Img As Image = Nothing

        If (cellState And DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) = DataGridViewElementStates.Selected Then
            textColor = parent.InheritedStyle.SelectionForeColor
        End If

        With New CoduriTari
            If IsDBNull(value) Then
                telValue = ""
                Img = Nothing

            ElseIf Me.RowIndex + 1 = parent.DataGridView.Rows.Count Then
                Img = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("phone_add")
                Img.Tag = "Adaugă telefon nou..."
                telValue = value

            Else
                For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(value, "\d+|^\D+")
                    Select Case .ExtractCountryFormTelephone(m.Groups(0).Value)
                        Case "RO"
                            telValue &= Strings.Join(Regex.Split(m.Groups(0).Value, "^(.{0,4})(.{0,3})(.{0,3})$"), " ")
                        Case "GB"
                            telValue &= Strings.Join(Regex.Split(.TelephoneWithoutPrefix(m.Groups(0).Value), "^(.{0,4})(.{0,6})$"), " ")

                        Case Else
                            Dim xValue As String = value

                            If Left(xValue, 1) = "+" Then
                                xValue = Mid(xValue, 2)
                            ElseIf Left(xValue, 2) = "00" Then
                                xValue = Mid(xValue, 3)
                            End If

                            telValue = String.Concat("+", Strings.Left(xValue, .LenghtCountryCode(xValue)), " ", Strings.Mid(xValue, .LenghtCountryCode(xValue) + 1))
                    End Select
                Next

                Img = .GetCoutryFlagFromTelephone(value)
                Img.Tag = .ExtractCountryFormTelephone(value)
            End If
        End With

        MyBase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, "", errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)
        If Img IsNot Nothing Then graphics.DrawImage(Img, New Rectangle(cellBounds.X + 2, CInt(cellBounds.Y + ((cellBounds.Height - Img.Height) / 2)), Math.Min(Img.Width, 24), 16))

        Using brush As New SolidBrush(textColor)
            graphics.DrawString(telValue, fnt, brush, New PointF(cellBounds.X + 26, (cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - graphics.MeasureString(telValue, fnt).Height) / 2)))
        End Using

    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)
        MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle)
        Dim ctl As TelefonEditingControl = TryCast(DataGridView.EditingControl, TelefonEditingControl)

        If Me.Value Is Nothing Or IsDBNull(Me.Value) Then
            ctl.Text = ""
        Else
            ctl.Text = Strings.Replace(Me.Value, Space(1), "")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(TelefonEditingControl)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ValueType As Type
        Get
            Return GetType(String)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue As Object
        Get
            Return "<Adaugă număr telefon>"
        End Get
    End Property
   ```

End Class

```
Public Class CoduriTari
    Private Enum CoduriTari
        [US] = 1
        [RU] = 7
        [EG] = 20
        .....
    End Enum

    Public Function ExtractCountryFormTelephone(Value As String) As String
        If Left(Value, 1) = "+" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 2)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "00" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 3)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "07" Or Left(Value, 2) = "03" Or Left(Value, 2) = "02" Then
            Value = "4" & Value
        End If

        For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
            If [Enum].GetName(GetType(CoduriTari), CType(Strings.Left(Value, i), Int32)) <> "" Then
                Return [Enum].GetName(GetType(CoduriTari), CType(Strings.Left(Value, i), Int32))
            End If
        Next

        Return ""
    End Function

    Public Function ExtractCountryCodeFromTelephone(Value As String) As Int32
        If Left(Value, 1) = "+" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 2)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "00" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 3)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "07" Or Left(Value, 2) = "03" Or Left(Value, 2) = "02" Then
            Value = "4" & Value
        End If

        For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
            If [Enum].GetName(GetType(CoduriTari), CType(Strings.Left(Value, i), Int32)) <> "" Then
                Return Left(Value, i)
            End If
        Next

        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function GetCoutryFlagFromTelephone(Value As String) As Image
        If Left(Value, 1) = "+" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 2)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "00" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 3)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "07" Or Left(Value, 2) = "03" Or Left(Value, 2) = "02" Then
            Value = "4" & Value
        End If

        For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
            If [Enum].GetName(GetType(CoduriTari), CType(Strings.Left(Regex.Match(Value, "\d+|^\D+").Groups(0).Value, i), Int32)) <> "" Then
                Return My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("flag_" & [Enum].GetName(GetType(CoduriTari), CType(Strings.Left(Regex.Match(Value, "\d+|^\D+").Groups(0).Value, i), Int32)).ToString & "_32")
            End If
        Next

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function LenghtCountryCode(value As String) As Integer
        If Left(value, 1) = "+" Then
            value = Mid(value, 2)
        ElseIf Left(value, 2) = "00" Then
            value = Mid(value, 3)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "07" Or Left(Value, 2) = "03" Or Left(Value, 2) = "02" Then
            value = "4" & value
        End If

        For i = 3 To 1 Step -1
            If [Enum].GetName(GetType(CoduriTari), CType(Strings.Left(value, i), Int32)) <> "" Then
                Return i
            End If
        Next

        Return 0

    End Function

    Public Function TelephoneWithoutPrefix(Value As String) As String
        If Left(Value, 1) = "+" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 2)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "00" Then
            Value = Mid(Value, 3)
        ElseIf Left(Value, 2) = "07" Or Left(Value, 2) = "03" Or Left(Value, 2) = "02" Then
            Value = "4" & Value
        End If

        Dim rg As New Regex(ExtractCountryCodeFromTelephone(Value).ToString)

        Return rg.Replace(Value, "", 1)
    End Function

End Class
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Do i need to create a custom DGV as well?

Comment: I don't think i understand something: why is the column new() sub being run for every cell?

Comment: No you don't need to create a custom DGV. In the cell class, add public properties for what you need to serialize **and** override the `Clone` function, clone and cast, and copy the properties values of the current instance to the cloned one then return it. Ex: `Dim c As TelefonColumn = CType(MyBase.Clone(), TelefonColumn) : c.SomeProperty = Me.SomeProperty : Return c`. Then use these properties to draw the cell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I must be missing something here.  To me this all seems like it would be far simpler to add this custom column to the source data collection and deal with it all there.  Leave the DVG for what it does best which is display data to the user

Comment: thank you dr null... i'll look into that :)

Comment: @Hursey: i can't do that. i need the flag and other info in the cell and i don't know how i could retreive from the server the info in one field...